# Algorithm to find subgroups based on a set of properties

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve a problem where I have data like that:

```
{
    1: [A, B, C],
    2: [A, B, C],
    3: [A, B, C],
    4: [A, B],
    5: [A, B],
    6: [A, B],
    7: [A],
    8: [A],
    9: [A],
    10: [A],
    11: [C, D],
    12: [C, D],
    13: [C, D],
    14: [C, D],
    15: [A, B, D],
    16: [A, B, D],
    17: [A, B, D],
    18: [A, B, D],
}
```

I have four groups A, B, C and D. They would be build up like so:

```
A consists of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,16,17,18]
B consists of [1,2,3,4,5,6,15,16,17,18]
C consists of [1,2,3,11,12,13,14]
D consists of [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

Now I want to find as few subgroups as possible to construct the groups:

```
SG_1 [1,2,3]
SG_2 [4,5,6]
SG_3 [15,16,17,18]
SG_4 [11,12,13,14]
SG_5 [7,8,9,10]
```

Which would lead to:

```
A consists of [SG_1, SG_2, SG_5, SG_4]
B consists of [SG_1, SG_2, SG_3]
C consists of [SG_1, SG_4]
D consists of [SG_4, SG_3]
```

I bet there is an algorithm for that, but I wasn't able to fine one. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What are the requirements and limitations of your assignment or exercise?

Comment: Hi, are you expecting the name of a standard algorithm or are you expecting some (pseudo) code as a solution to this problem? Also have you tried any coding as of yet?

Comment: @Krokodil A name or hit would be great, so I know what to search for. If someone is willing to provide pseudo code even better :D

Comment: @Some programmer dude The only requirements are:
1) each element (1,2, etc.) is only linked to one subgroup
2) as few subgroups as possible
3) subgroups can be nested

Comment: With only one group this would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem, for which there is no good algorithm. Adding another 3 groups does not make this easier.

Comment: If you pay a bit of attention, you notice that 1, 2 and 3 are all labeled with the same label [A, B, C] and they all go to the same subgroup,  4, 5 and 6 are all labeled with the same label [A, B] and they all go to the same subgroup, 7, 8, 9 and 10 are all labeled with the same label [A] and they all go to the same subgroup, 11, 12, 13 and 14 are all labeled with the same label [C, D] and they all go to the same subgroup, and 15, 16, 17 and 18 are all labeled with the same label [A, B, D] and they all go to the same subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, this problem is similar to the Set cover problem but there is one simplification in the format of the input data:

```
{
    1: [A, B, C],
    2: [A, B, C],
    3: [A, B, C],
    4: [A, B],
    ...
}
```

## The simplification

1. This format does not allow for the same group member (in this example the numbers 1-4) to appear more than once in a group (eg A, B etc).
2. Also members should not appear in a different order in different groups (eg A, B) because groups are specified together in one array for each member.

I have provided logic to ensure the output is still correct if the second point is not true; but the first must be true.

## How I approached the problem

1. As any other difficult problem, the first thing I did was copy down the requirements and test data, and then power off my computer.
2. On a piece of paper I tried solving the problem myself to see what the computer needs to do later. No programming yet.
3. Then I described the process of how to separate this data into subgroups in the same way I would to a child.
4. Then I began breaking it down into smaller and smaller individual steps. This is called structured English. Below is my structured English description.
   For this first description, I am writing it so it works specifically for the test data:

```
group A consists of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,16,17,18]
group B consists of [1,2,3,4,5,6,15,16,17,18]
group C consists of [1,2,3,11,12,13,14]
group D consists of [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

[image]

The main idea is that I am starting at the first group, A, and going through each element.

- Each time a new subgroup should be created,

  - the current element is added to this new empty array, called subgroup or sg.
  - the range of this sg within each group is stored
  - eg if a sg is [1,2,3], then its range for the group A could be index 0 -> 2
- if there is a subgroup, then the current element is added to it if it is in the same groups as the previous element.
- if not, then the sg is done, and a new sg is created
- this continues until all groups and all elements within all the groups are visited, but we skip elements that are references to subgroups - they have already been visited (in (pseudo)"parallel" to equivalent elements from other groups).

5. Next, I manually traced out these instructions and did some simple paper-based debugging to construct the next lower-level structured english description, included below. After that I traced it again and added some notes to it (see *s on the picture below).
   [image]

And this is the final product. To test whether it works I re-wrote this pseudocode/structured english as JavaScript just to see if it works really quickly before I post this answer.

## The JavaScript implementation example

Of course there were some small bugs which turned up which were hidden in the translation from higher-level lines in my description to an actual programming language, but after those were eliminated, the solution worked.

If you don't want to have to translate the structured english to a programming language yourself, you can just run my JavaScript below. Any problems or misunderstood requirements, tell me.

Just really quickly before I give you the actual code, I'll include some small functions I defined that are used by the main algorithm:

The test data is defined like so:

```js
const A = "A";
const B = "B";
const C = "C";
const D = "D";

const data = {
  1: [A, B, C],
  2: [A, B, C],
  3: [A, B, C],
  4: [A, B],
  5: [A, B],
  6: [A, B],
  7: [A],
  8: [A],
  9: [A],
  10: [A],
  11: [C, D],
  12: [C, D],
  13: [C, D],
  14: [C, D],
  15: [A, B, D],
  16: [A, B, D],
  17: [A, B, D],
  18: [A, B, D],
};
```

And to convert it to the alternate format like `A consists of [1,2,3,...]` I use this funciton:

```js
function findGroups(data) {
  const groups = {};
  for (const member of Object.keys(data)) {
    const curGroups = data[member];
    
    curGroups.forEach(group => {
      const arr = groups[group] || new Array();
      arr.push(member);
      groups[group] = arr;
    });
  }
  
  return groups;
}
```

Next, I wrote a function to count the number of times an element appears in the groups:

```js
function countElmntAppearances(elmntVal, groupsData) {
  let appearances = 0;
  const groups = Object.values(groupsData);
  for(const group of groups) {
    if(group.includes(elmntVal)) {
      appearances++;
    }
  }
  return appearances;
}
```

Next, this funciton returns true if the two arrays passed have the same elements in the same order:

```js
function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  if(arr1 === arr2) return true;
  if(arr1 == null || arr2 == null) return false;
  if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

After that, this one returns an array of the names of the groups that a particular element is found in:

```js
function getGroupsElmntIsIn(elmntVal, groupsData) {
  const groups = Object.values(groupsData);
  const names = Object.keys(groupsData);

  const grpsElmntIsIn = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if(groups[i].includes(elmntVal)) {
      grpsElmntIsIn.push(names[i]);
    }
  }
  return grpsElmntIsIn;
}
```

The next function is used only if your data could include groups having a different order of elements than other groups. If your data won't do that, then you could remove this function and instead use the above one. An example of differently ordered elements is

```
A consists of [1,2,4,5]
B consists of [1,2,3,4,5]
```

So here 4 is after 2 in A and after 3 in B.

Here is the function to protect against this:

```js
function getGroupsElmntIsAdjacentToPrevIn(elmntVal, groupsData, groupName, elmntIndex) {
  if(elmntIndex === 0) {
    return getGroupsElmntIsIn(elmntVal, groupsData)
  }

  const groups = structuredClone(Object.values(groupsData));
  const names = Object.keys(groupsData);

  const prevElmnt = groupsData[groupName][elmntIndex-1];

  const grpsElmntIsIn = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    const group = groups[i];

    if(group.indexOf(elmntVal) === 1+group.indexOf(prevElmnt)) {
      grpsElmntIsIn.push(names[i]);
    }
  }
  return grpsElmntIsIn;
}
```

It returns an array of groups that the passed element is in, but only if the element is after the same previous element in those groups.

And finally, here is the actual algorithm:

```js
function findSubGroups(groupsData) {
  const groupsNames = Object.keys(groupsData); // array of strings
  const groupsValues = Object.values(groupsData); // array of arrays of ints (but written as strings in this case)

  const sgData = {};
  let subgroupNum = 1;
  let prevElmntIsolated = false;

  // for each group
  for(let groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < groupsNames.length; groupIndex++) {
    const groupName = groupsNames[groupIndex];
    const group = groupsValues[groupIndex];

    let ranges = {};
    let subgroup = [];

    // for each element in group:
    for(let elmntIndex = 0; elmntIndex < group.length; elmntIndex++) {
      // skip references to subgroups:
      const elmnt = group[elmntIndex];
      if(elmnt.toString().includes("SG_")) {
        continue;
      }

      // if elmnt is only in this group, put it in its own sg:
      if(countElmntAppearances(elmnt, groupsData) === 1) {
        subgroup.push(elmnt);
        ranges[groupName] = {
          start: ranges[groupName]?.start ?? elmntIndex,
          end: elmntIndex
        };
        // yeah i didnt know what to call this variable:
        prevElmntIsolated = true;
        // it's true if the current elmnt is isolated ie only in this group 
        // and no other
        // it's used in the next iteration to check whether the subgroup needs to end
        continue;
      }
      if(prevElmntIsolated) {
        // the prev elmnt was only in this group
        // but this one isnt anymore
        // so save the subgroup so far and then process this elmnt
        sgData["SG_"+subgroupNum] = subgroup;
        // now replace ranges in the groups with reference to the sg
        const howmany = ranges[groupName].end - ranges[groupName].start;
        const removed = groupsData[groupName].splice(ranges[groupName].start+1, howmany);
        groupsData[groupName][ranges[groupName].start] = "SG_"+subgroupNum;
        // clear sg and ranges
        subgroup = [];
        ranges = {};
        subgroupNum++;
        prevElmntIsolated = false;
        elmntIndex -= removed.length;
      }


      //console.log(elmnt, Object.keys(ranges));
      // if ranges do not exist, elmnt is first in new subgroup:
      if(subgroup.length === 0) {
        // create the new subgroup with the new elmnt
        subgroup = [elmnt];
        //ranges[groupName] = {start: elmntIndex, end: elmntIndex};
        //ranges for each group .start and .end be set
        for(const grpNm of getGroupsElmntIsIn(elmnt, groupsData)) {
          const grp = groupsData[grpNm];
          const index = grp.indexOf(elmnt);
          ranges[grpNm] = {
            start: index,
            end: index
          };
        }
      } else {
        // else there is a subgroup (sg) and ranges from before
        // if elmnt is still in same groups as prev. elmnt:
        if(arraysEqual(getGroupsElmntIsAdjacentToPrevIn(elmnt, groupsData, groupName, elmntIndex), Object.keys(ranges))) {
          // then update ranges for all these groups
          for (const grpNm of Object.keys(ranges)) {
            // update the ranges
            ranges[grpNm].end++; // todo make it support non adjacent elmnts, return false (not in same group for the if statement above if they are not adjacent eg one group is 1,2,3 and the other is 1, 1.4, 2)
          }
          subgroup.push(elmnt);
        } else {
          // missing from >= 1 group
          // end this sg, save it into sgData
          sgData["SG_"+subgroupNum] = subgroup;
          // now replace ranges in the groups with reference to the sg
          for (const grpNm of Object.keys(ranges)) {
            const howmany = ranges[grpNm].end - ranges[grpNm].start;
            const removed = groupsData[grpNm].splice(ranges[grpNm].start+1, howmany);
            groupsData[grpNm][ranges[grpNm].start] = "SG_"+subgroupNum;
          }
          // clear sg and ranges
          subgroup = [];
          ranges = {};
          // create the new subgroup with the new elmnt
          subgroupNum++;
        }
      }
    }
    // end of group, end current sg and go to next group
    // now save current state of subgroup into sgData
    if(subgroup.length === 0) {
      continue; // if there aren't any elmnts in the subgroup, go to next group
    }
    sgData["SG_"+subgroupNum] = subgroup;
    // now replace ranges in the groups with reference to the sg
    for (const grpNm of Object.keys(ranges)) {
      const howmany = ranges[grpNm].end - ranges[grpNm].start;
      const removed = groupsData[grpNm].splice(ranges[grpNm].start+1, howmany);
      groupsData[grpNm][ranges[grpNm].start] = "SG_"+subgroupNum;
    }
    // finally clear sg and ranges
    subgroup = [];
    ranges = {};
    subgroupNum++;
  }

  return {
    groups: groupsData,
    subgroups: sgData
  };
}
```

## Inline demo

Here is an inline demo to run it:

```js
const A = "A";
const B = "B";
const C = "C";
const D = "D";

const data = {
  1: [A, B, C],
  2: [A, B, C],
  3: [A, B, C],
  4: [A, B],
  5: [A, B],
  6: [A, B],
  7: [A],
  8: [A],
  9: [A],
  10: [A],
  11: [C, D],
  12: [C, D],
  13: [C, D],
  14: [C, D],
  15: [A, B, D],
  16: [A, B, D],
  17: [A, B, D],
  18: [A, B, D],
};



function findGroups(data) {
  const groups = {};
  for (const member of Object.keys(data)) {
    const curGroups = data[member];
    
    curGroups.forEach(group => {
      const arr = groups[group] || new Array();
      arr.push(member);
      groups[group] = arr;
    });
  }
  
  return groups;
}



function countElmntAppearances(elmntVal, groupsData) {
  let appearances = 0;
  const groups = Object.values(groupsData);
  for(const group of groups) {
    if(group.includes(elmntVal)) {
      appearances++;
    }
  }
  return appearances;
}

function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  if(arr1 === arr2) return true;
  if(arr1 == null || arr2 == null) return false;
  if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function getGroupsElmntIsIn(elmntVal, groupsData) {
  const groups = Object.values(groupsData);
  const names = Object.keys(groupsData);

  const grpsElmntIsIn = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if(groups[i].includes(elmntVal)) {
      grpsElmntIsIn.push(names[i]);
    }
  }
  return grpsElmntIsIn;
}

function getGroupsElmntIsAdjacentToPrevIn(elmntVal, groupsData, groupName, elmntIndex) {
  if(elmntIndex === 0) {
    return getGroupsElmntIsIn(elmntVal, groupsData)
  }

  const groups = structuredClone(Object.values(groupsData));
  const names = Object.keys(groupsData);

  const prevElmnt = groupsData[groupName][elmntIndex-1];

  const grpsElmntIsIn = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    const group = groups[i];

    if(group.indexOf(elmntVal) === 1+group.indexOf(prevElmnt)) {
      grpsElmntIsIn.push(names[i]);
    }
  }
  return grpsElmntIsIn;
}



function findSubGroups(groupsData) {
  const groupsNames = Object.keys(groupsData); // array of strings
  const groupsValues = Object.values(groupsData); // array of arrays of ints (but written as strings in this case)

  const sgData = {};
  let subgroupNum = 1;
  let prevElmntIsolated = false;

  // for each group
  for(let groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < groupsNames.length; groupIndex++) {
    const groupName = groupsNames[groupIndex];
    const group = groupsValues[groupIndex];

    let ranges = {};
    let subgroup = [];

    // for each element in group:
    for(let elmntIndex = 0; elmntIndex < group.length; elmntIndex++) {
      // skip references to subgroups:
      const elmnt = group[elmntIndex];
      if(elmnt.toString().includes("SG_")) {
        continue;
      }

      // if elmnt is only in this group, put it in its own sg:
      if(countElmntAppearances(elmnt, groupsData) === 1) {
        subgroup.push(elmnt);
        ranges[groupName] = {
          start: ranges[groupName]?.start ?? elmntIndex,
          end: elmntIndex
        };
        // yeah i didnt know what to call this variable:
        prevElmntIsolated = true;
        // it's true if the current elmnt is isolated ie only in this group 
        // and no other
        // it's used in the next iteration to check whether the subgroup needs to end
        continue;
      }
      if(prevElmntIsolated) {
        // the prev elmnt was only in this group
        // but this one isnt anymore
        // so save the subgroup so far and then process this elmnt
        sgData["SG_"+subgroupNum] = subgroup;
        // now replace ranges in the groups with reference to the sg
        const howmany = ranges[groupName].end - ranges[groupName].start;
        const removed = groupsData[groupName].splice(ranges[groupName].start+1, howmany);
        groupsData[groupName][ranges[groupName].start] = "SG_"+subgroupNum;
        // clear sg and ranges
        subgroup = [];
        ranges = {};
        subgroupNum++;
        prevElmntIsolated = false;
        elmntIndex -= removed.length;
      }


      //console.log(elmnt, Object.keys(ranges));
      // if ranges do not exist, elmnt is first in new subgroup:
      if(subgroup.length === 0) {
        // create the new subgroup with the new elmnt
        subgroup = [elmnt];
        //ranges[groupName] = {start: elmntIndex, end: elmntIndex};
        //ranges for each group .start and .end be set
        for(const grpNm of getGroupsElmntIsIn(elmnt, groupsData)) {
          const grp = groupsData[grpNm];
          const index = grp.indexOf(elmnt);
          ranges[grpNm] = {
            start: index,
            end: index
          };
        }
      } else {
        // else there is a subgroup (sg) and ranges from before
        // if elmnt is still in same groups as prev. elmnt:
        if(arraysEqual(getGroupsElmntIsAdjacentToPrevIn(elmnt, groupsData, groupName, elmntIndex), Object.keys(ranges))) {
          // then update ranges for all these groups
          for (const grpNm of Object.keys(ranges)) {
            // update the ranges
            ranges[grpNm].end++; // todo make it support non adjacent elmnts, return false (not in same group for the if statement above if they are not adjacent eg one group is 1,2,3 and the other is 1, 1.4, 2)
          }
          subgroup.push(elmnt);
        } else {
          // missing from >= 1 group
          // end this sg, save it into sgData
          sgData["SG_"+subgroupNum] = subgroup;
          // now replace ranges in the groups with reference to the sg
          for (const grpNm of Object.keys(ranges)) {
            const howmany = ranges[grpNm].end - ranges[grpNm].start;
            const removed = groupsData[grpNm].splice(ranges[grpNm].start+1, howmany);
            groupsData[grpNm][ranges[grpNm].start] = "SG_"+subgroupNum;
          }
          // clear sg and ranges
          subgroup = [];
          ranges = {};
          // create the new subgroup with the new elmnt
          subgroupNum++;
        }
      }
    }
    // end of group, end current sg and go to next group
    // now save current state of subgroup into sgData
    if(subgroup.length === 0) {
      continue; // if there aren't any elmnts in the subgroup, go to next group
    }
    sgData["SG_"+subgroupNum] = subgroup;
    // now replace ranges in the groups with reference to the sg
    for (const grpNm of Object.keys(ranges)) {
      const howmany = ranges[grpNm].end - ranges[grpNm].start;
      const removed = groupsData[grpNm].splice(ranges[grpNm].start+1, howmany);
      groupsData[grpNm][ranges[grpNm].start] = "SG_"+subgroupNum;
    }
    // finally clear sg and ranges
    subgroup = [];
    ranges = {};
    subgroupNum++;
  }

  return {
    groups: groupsData,
    subgroups: sgData
  };
}



console.log("With the test data in the OP:");
console.log(
  findSubGroups(
    findGroups(data)
  )
);
```

Note that in the OP the desired result for group A is wrong, the last sg for A should be the same as the last sg for D.

Please review this code and suggest improvements.